# full path to upload files to server

Tags: php

I'm getting error while uploading files

I created function that uploads files. the problem is that I'm calling it from different file and different folders, which means that my path to the image folder's is changing.
because of that i'm using the full path.

(I do have folder named - "images/usersFiles")

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://localhost/dogger/images/usersFiles/13981072220-1.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\dogger\func\func.global.php on line 127

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\tmp\php9D89.tmp' to 'http://localhost/dogger/images/usersFiles/13981072220-1.jpg' in C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\dogger\func\func.global.php on line 127
```

I'm running the code from my local computer:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "127.0.0.1")
    $usersFiles = 'http://localhost/dogger/images/usersFiles/';  
else
    $usersFiles = '/home/israelig/public_html/sites/dogger/images/usersFiles/';  


if (move_uploaded_file($files['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $usersFiles.$files['file']['name'][$i]))
```

Comment: you want to store files in http://localhost/dogger/images/usersFiles/ directory? that's funny)

Comment: Use relative paths. They will work both on localhost and on the server..

Comment: @user3396295 obviously it's not possible

Comment: @user3396295 if in doubt check out the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: if I will remove the "http://" than i won't be able to see the images i uploaded (i'll see small X instead the image, although the folder and image exist...)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, `move_uploaded_file` doesn't support writing to HTTP. You have to use a *local file path*, not a URL.

Comment: if I will remove the "http://" than i won't be able to see the images i uploaded (i'll see small X instead the image, although the folder and image exist...)

Comment: @user3396295 — You use the local file path when moving the file. You use the URL when telling the browser where to find it. You don't use either for both.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path without http, like this (I dont use windows and can mistake):

> C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\dogger\userFiles

You can generate this path with:

```
realpath(dir(__FILE__) . '/../userFiles')
```

where **FILE** contains path of current script

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
if (move_uploaded_file($files['file']['tmp_name'], '/path/to/userFiles/'.$files['file']['name']))
{
    echo "File uploaded.";
    echo "<img src='/path/to/userFiles/{$files['file']['name']}' />";
}
```

**EDIT:**

Your directory structure:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\
|-----------------------wamp\
                           |--www\
                                |---dogger\   <-- Assuming here is your upload.php which will be uploading image.
                                      |-----images\
                                               |-----usersFiles\    <-- Image will be uploaded here.
```

**wamp\www\dogger\upload.php**

```
<?php
    if (move_uploaded_file($files['file']['tmp_name'], './images/usersFiles/'.$files['file']['name']))
    {
        echo "File uploaded.<br/>";
        echo "<img src='./images/usersFiles/{$files['file']['name']}' />"; //displaying image using relative path.
        //OR
        echo "<img src='http://localhost/dogger/images/usersFiles/{$files['file']['name']}' />"; //displaying image using absolute path
    }

?>
```

Comment: if I will remove the "http://" than i won't be able to see the images i uploaded (i'll see small X instead the image, although the folder and image exist...)

Comment: @user3396295, while dealing with files from server side (here PHP), we need to deal with actual file location in server. But if you want to show on browser using any URL then you'l need to show it using absolute/relative path from `www`, `htdocs` or `public_html` directory.

Comment: @user3396295, see updated answer. I think now you'l understand better